# Get all images from a folder in my project/solution

Tags: c#, file

A quick question.

How do i in the easiest and securest way get all images from a folder in my solution without having to copy them to the debug folder.

So lets say this is my folder structure:

```
Project
   Resources (Folder)
       Images (Folder)
          HelpIcons (Folder)
             Icon1.png
             Icon2.png
```

How do i get the icon1 and icon2 from the code? (without copy to debug)

Comment: do you mean without manually copying them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GetFiles from the directory you specified.

```
String[] filenames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("Project\\Resources\\Images\\HelpIcons");
```

`filenames` contains a list of all filenames in that directory, from here you can then look for ".png"

--Edit 12:13--

This will be starting from the directory where your executable is.
You can specify the full path if needed.

```
String[] filenames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Project\\Resources\\Images\\HelpIcons");
```

Comment: it tries to look in my debug folder.. so it looks in this folder which doesn't exist: 
"bin\debug\project\resources\images\helpicons\"

Comment: hmm.. the second solution isn't that safe.. what if the program is moved, it ain't working anymore..

Comment: what do you mean by the program is moved? You'll have to specify the full path if your root folder ("Project" in this case) is not in the same directory as the executable, otherwise your program won't know where to look.

Comment: yeah but the program won't always be located in the C:\\project folder.. it's an WPF application.. and Proejct\\Resources\\images doesn't work..

Comment: maybe you can try relative path? I do not know where exactly your files are so I don't know how to help you with it. "..\\Project" might or might not work, you can give it a try

Answer (score 1):

You can do some like `Server.MapPath("~/Images/HelpIcons")` or whatever the virtual path is if this is in a web project.

Alternatively, you can get the current execution directory and work your way from there `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.71).aspx

Once you have the starting point you get children directories with `Directory.GetDirectories(string path)` and the files with `Directory.GetFiles(string path)`

Comment: hmm.. the Directory.GetCurrentDirectory leads me to the debug folder.. how to i go 2 steps back?

Comment: `Directory.GetParent(string path)` or `Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(currentPath,"../.."))`

Comment: this did the job, thanks! 
Final string: string imagesPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName

Answer (score -1):

If it is in a compiled section of code you should be able to just hit the root and then come back up to the directory e.g. /Resources/Images/HelpIcons/

If you are accessing the images from a front end file e.g .aspx try ~/Resources/Images/HelpIcons

Comment: could you please give an example by some code or anything? :-)

Comment: Are you just trying to get the images to show up on a web page? or do you just want the path so you have a handle to manipulate them?