# how to get image url from my project image folder?

Tags: c#, wpf

My requirement to get image from images folder from my current stimulation explore.

[image]

we need access image from Images folder.

My code is gives an error at **ImageSource MoleImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(".Images/Section5Q4femail1.pngeMole"));** line

```
private Image CreateImage()
    {
        Image Mole = new Image();
        Mole.Width = 25;
        Mole.Height = 25;
        ImageSource MoleImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(".Images/Section5Q4femail1.pngeMole"));
        Mole.Source = MoleImage;
        return Mole;
    }
```

Comment: i think this will help you  see this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704304/get-all-images-from-a-folder-in-my-project-solution

Comment: Bind to it from Xaml imo.

Answer (score 0):

Create Uri object like this

```
new Uri("/Earnest_Individuals;component/Images/Section5Q4femail1.pngeMole");
```

where Earnest_Individuals is your project assembly name.